# Ubuntu - File permissions. How to append a file by user after it was created by crontab

Tags: permissions, cron

I have a python code logging its actions on a `txtfile.log`, which appends to this file every time code runs.

Mostly- this code runs using `crontab`.

The problem happens when `user` is running this code for the first time, then `txtfile.org` is created under `user`'s permissions. But after reboot ( now file exists ) same code fails to run, when trying to append to this file.
And on the other side- when file is initially created by `root` after first run using `crontab`, `user` can run this code, since he has no permissions to write to a `root` file.

What is the correct way solving it ?

Comment: Who *should* own the file, user or root or somebody else?

Comment: As said- mostly it is a crontab job, which means it has `root` permissions, but I hope there is a way that both `root` and `user` will be able to execute this code without the need to delete this log file.

Comment: If you use the user's own crontab (`crontab -e` rather than `sudo crontab -e`, or add an appropriate `user` field if you are using the system's `/etc/crontab` file), the file should remain owned by the user

Comment: @steeldriver thank you- i'll give it a try, and post again

Comment: Do either `crontab -u guy -e` or `1 2 * * * sudo -u username "/path/to/my/scriptfile.sh` or `1 2 * * * su username -c "/path/to/my/scriptfile.sh"` as root to get it to run as that user